# How to split build.gradle file into files with smaller tasks

Tags: java, gradle

My build file is big and hard to maintain, how to split the build file into separate files with smaller tasks to be imported into the main gradle file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'other.gradle'
```

**other.gradle**

```
println "configuring $project"
task hello << {
    println 'hello from other script'
}
```

**Output of gradle -q hello**

```
> gradle -q hello
configuring root project 'configureProjectUsingScript'
hello from other script
```

Source: [Configuring the project using an external build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3Aconfiguring_using_external_script)